# Laravel Passport installation error on the live hosting

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install laravel passport on a live hosting but it's giving me this error in the terminal, Help me if possible :)

````
  Problem 1
    - league/flysystem 1.0.53 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.53 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.53 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.0.53) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.53].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/alt/php72/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/alt/php72/link/conf/alt_php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have ext-fileinfo but Composer says it is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850136/i-have-ext-fileinfo-but-composer-says-it-is-missing)

Comment: Let me check it

Answer (score 1):

You must enable the `fileinfo` extension by removing the starting semicolon ( ; ) from your php.ini

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

And then restart your web server

Comment: /etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Yeah got it let me try this now

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache

Comment: But I am working on a live terminal (Hosting terminal) , so is it necessary to restart apache here as well ?

Comment: yes you must restart it :  sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: But I am using windows

Comment: Your live project hosting is under windows environment ?

Comment: yes sir it's under windows env