# Trying to install Laravel using composer and it says "the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.3].
    - league/flysystem 1.1.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for league/mime-type-detection 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection 1.4.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - league/flysystem 1.1.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.26.1 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.34 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.3].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.26.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.26.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: Please improve your question so that it is acceptable to the stackoverflow community. the inquiry and the answer is relevant and it's the number one return from google currently. the edit queue is currently full unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer error: "PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850136/composer-error-php-extension-fileinfo-is-missing-from-your-system)

Answer (score 13):

You have disabled the *fileinfo extension* from php. To enable extension, verify that are enabled in the .ini file (find/add line "`extension=fileinfo`" in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`).
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, stop the XAMPP/Wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; ) from your xampp\php\php.ini the following code.

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

to

```
extension=fileinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this.

**You have disabled the fileinfo extension from PHP. You have to enable it.**

1. You have to go to the location where PHP is installed and **open the "php.ini" file using a text editor**. ( Might be installed in C://Program Files or the location you installed it)
2. If you don't know the location run "**php --ini**" to find where it is.

> php --ini

3. Search for **extension=fileinfo**
   If that line has a "**;**" at the start, **remove the ";"** and save it.

It should be changed from

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

to

```
extension=fileinfo
```

This worked for me.