# Get an error when executing a command ($ laravel new my_website)

Tags: terminal, composer-php, laravel-8, ubuntu-20.04

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.3.3, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.3.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.3.3, ..., 9.5.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I get this error when executing the (new) command in Ubuntu 20 terminal
I also use Laravel 8 version.
How should I fix this error?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have ext-fileinfo but Composer says it is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850136/i-have-ext-fileinfo-but-composer-says-it-is-missing)

Comment: If that does not help, please add more details and your attempts to resolve that error