# Trying to composer update this error came up on CentOs

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, centos7, php-extension

I'm trying to deploy my laravel project on CentOs system. When im going to run composer update command I am encountering this error. I can't figure out the solution and I searched for solution in this platform. I found for windows but not work on my CentOs system.

Solution for Windows:

I am going to add this line in php.ini file: `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` but didn't work.

Error Message;

```
Continue as root/super user [yes]? yes
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
 Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Comment: So you have absolutely no experience with CentOS?

Comment: No, sorry. I am new in centos :/

Comment: What CentOS version are you using? Using PHP-FPM?

Comment: How can i learn that info

Comment: Well, for starters the manual, secondly a search engine of your likings, pretty much the first result when using Google

Comment: probably CentOs 7

Comment: my phpinfo() page says: Linux 92.xxx.xxx.xxx(Ip address)

Comment: I‘m sorry, but I‘m not going to guide someone unexperienced with CentOS or Linux in general for that matter

Comment: I‘ve removed the `laravel` tag and added the `php-extension` to attract less attention in the laravel-crowd and more in the Linux/CentOS-crowd in the hopes that someone takes some time to explains the appropriate steps

Comment: I solved the problem by upgrading php version and laravel version. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Niko: Please add your solution as an answer, also by adding a little bit more detail, e.g. how you upgraded the PHP version and to which version. Same for Laravel. This should help your future self and other visitors. After a short period of time you can mark the answer as accepted then. More info of how this works should also be available in the [help].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer error: "PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850136/composer-error-php-extension-fileinfo-is-missing-from-your-system)

Answer (score 1):

One of your required package need a specific php extension in your CentOs system.

See the 2nd line error message thrown by composer update

```
- league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] 
 require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. 
 Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
```

Please enable this missing php extension by uncomment it from inside your CentOs php.ini

The missing extension is *ext-fileinfo*

Note: also a good idea to run "composer install" when deploying your project in new environment, to minimize sudden package version updated that might trigger installation issues.
Also dont forget to upload your composer.lock as well.
Have a look at documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#autoloader-optimization

Comment: when i run composer install, it says: please run composer update

Comment: i did it. But didn't work on CentOs

Comment: What error did you get now after enable required extension ?

Comment: Also i notice u you php8.1 , are u using laravel 9 latest? And you local env using the same php configuration? Or lower?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem again and resolved it as follows:

After installing the File Info extension and other necessary packages via EasyApache in the WHM panel, my problem was completely resolved. Thanks to everyone.